# How to get all number between a and b? (0 - 100)

Tags: javascript, string, caret

I have an array of objects like this:

```
let arr = [{start: 0, end: 50, id: '55'}, {start: 51, end: 100, id: '66'}];
```

Also I have a string, for example in this case we have string with length `100`;

So when I click on the some position in the string I can get caret position:

```
  const range = window.getSelection()?.getRangeAt(0);
  const preCaretRange = range?.cloneRange();
  preCaretRange?.selectNodeContents(element);
  caretCharOffset = preCaretRange?.toString().length || 0;
```

My aim - to get object's id when i click on some position in the string.

It means that when i click on the `33` index - I'll get id `55`, when I click on the `87` index,I'll get id `66` etc. How I can do this, can anybody help me?

Comment: loop the arr and find `id` of the first match?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? If you don't care about performance, just loop, otherwise, use a binary search tree.

Comment: @lastr2d2 id of element which caret position is between or equal to start/end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be multiple ranges where the position will match, you could use for example reduce and check if the value is greater or equal to the start value, and lesser or equal to the end value.

Then aggregate the value of the id property.

```js
let arr = [{start: 0, end: 50, id: '55'}, {start: 51, end: 100, id: '66'}];
const getObjectId = pos => {
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (pos >= c.start && pos <= c.end) {
      a.push(c.id);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getObjectId(33));
console.log(getObjectId(87));
```

If there is only a single return value possible, you can use a for loop for example and return the value on the first matching occurrence.

```js
let arr = [{start: 0, end: 50, id: '55'}, {start: 51, end: 100, id: '66'}];
const getObjectId = pos => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    let p = arr[i];
    if (pos >= p.start && pos <= p.end) {
      return p.id;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getObjectId(33));
console.log(getObjectId(87));
```